# Pose mode lags with a specific armature

Tags: bones

I have a lot of lags, and I almost crash when I move or select bones in pose mode only with a specific armature. I search on google similar issues during 3 hours but I didnt find anything. I install 4 different versions of blender (2.8, 2.83, 2.83.3 and 2.90), the lags appear in 2.83.3 version. I dont have subsurf modifier activated or solidify

Comment: If you go to the Viewport Overlays dropdown and enable "Show Statistics", then select the related character mesh controlled by the armature, put into EDIT mode and 'a' to select all vertices: does that mesh have an unusually higher vertex count than your other meshes controlled by armatures that are well behaved?  You may be overwhelming your machine that contains a very high mesh could, and may need to simplify the mesh.

Comment: Hi ! Its not about the mesh, if I hide the mesh I still have lags

Comment: Hiding the mesh will not stop all the calculations of the influence of armature on the mesh that may be slowing this down.   In a copy of the file, try DELETING the mesh and see if that restores your performance. If no difference then it’s not the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Your rig may have extra objects parented to it, which causes the problem.

Make sure your rig doesn't have any unnecessary mesh, curves, etc parented to it.